# Break for loop in R

Tags: r, loops, break

I have

```
sx <- structure(c(17, 11, 4, 0, 17, 11, 9, 15, 26, 12, 9, 0, 11, 9, 12, 5, 0, 9), .Dim = c(3L, 6L))
```

I need to break the value = 0. I used that function:

```
for (i in 1:ncol(sx)) {
  for (j in 1:nrow(sx)) {
    if (sx[j,i] == 0) {
      break
    }
    else 
    {
      sx[j,i] <- sx[j,i]
    }
  }
}
```

but it doesn't work. My expected output is

```
sx <- structure(c(17, 11, 4, 9, 17, 11, 12, 15, 26, 11, 9, 12, 9, 5, 9), .Dim = c(3L, 5L))
```

How can I do? Thx

Comment: Why do you need a nested for loop?  If I understand `sx[, seq_len(which(sx == 0)[1]-1), drop = FALSE]`.  Also, your example shows only a single row.  So, it is not clear about your expected with more rows

Comment: If you check `?break` - `Both break and next apply only to the innermost of nested loops.`

Comment: Question edited

Comment: can you update with the expected output as well (for the new example).  Your `else` is simply returning the same value `sx[j,i] <- sx[j,i]`

Comment: Yes, because if  sx[j,i] isn't = 0 I don't want break it

Comment: Sorry, without an expected output, it is difficult to know what you wanted especially when your loop is not working

Comment: Ok, I added the expected output

Comment: You don't need a double loop `t(apply(sx, 1, \(x) x[x !=0]))`

Comment: If the number of 0s are different in each row, then `lst1 <- apply(sx, 1, \(x) x[x!= 0], simplify = FALSE); mx <- max(lengths(lst1));
do.call(rbind, lapply(lst1, "length<-", mx));`

Comment: If your expected output was edited to `5,9,9)` rather than your `9,5,9)` that I take to be a typo, there would be less lingering head scratch and akrun's final comment handles all stated cases.